# GitHub Pages not pulling images

Tags: html, git, github, github-pages

I am very new to GitHub. I made a repo with my main project in it and everything seems to be working fine. I then made another repo and even though HTML and CSS seem to be pulling through alright my images won't show up.

I understand GitHub is case sensitive and I don't believe that's the issue. My only theory is that maybe because it's not the main repo the path of the images should change on my markup? I have no clue. It's been up for nearly an hour so it couldn't be that it needs a couple of minutes to pull the images either.

Here is the link to the repo https://github.com/NikolaosKalfas/fleshformers.git 
(I hope this is how you link a repo).

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you checked to see that the images are actually where the markup says they are?

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing this right as I do not know how to direct the markup on different repos on GitHub. In my local setup and when I was hosting online this markup worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is currently being visible at https://nikolaoskalfas.github.io/fleshformers/. You use absolute paths for images, like `/dist/images/Logo.png`. This makes the full URL to the image https://nikolaoskalfas.github.io/dist/images/Logo.png and Github returns error 404 as it doesn't have the image at the URL. The correct URL is https://nikolaoskalfas.github.io/fleshformers/dist/images/Logo.png.

My advice is to use relative URLs like `../dist/images/Logo.png` or `../../dist/images/Logo.png` depending on the path to the HTML files. This way your site will work regardless of the prefix.

Comment: There is a "dist" directory in the nikolaoskalfas repo as well. From what you are saying am I correct to assume that `../dist/images/Logo.png` would try and pull from that one and not the one in the fleshformers repo? Because I tried your solution and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Directory `dist` doesn't help because browsers don't access it. The URL for the Logo image is currently https://nikolaoskalfas.github.io/dist/images/Logo.png because it's written in HTML as `/dist/images/Logo.png`. The URL must be https://nikolaoskalfas.github.io/fleshformers/dist/images/Logo.png. As for "still doesn't work" — for HTMLs in the root folder the relative path is `./dist/` or simply `dist/` (without the leading slash).